# CSS combination of active & before not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I'm wondering why I cannot find anything about this issue. On Firefox the :active selector isn't working when it is an `<a>` with a `::before`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<style>
.test {
    border: 1px solid #0dd;
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: 3rem;
    width: 3rem;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: blue;
}

.test::before{
    content: "ABC";
    color: tomato;
}

.test:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button class='test'>_1</button>
<a class='test' href="#">_2</a>
<a class='test'>_3</a>

</body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/vhe5u57n/)

To reproduce it:

1. Browser Firefox 58.02
2. click on the grey area of the button / link or on the blue text. The :active selector applies, the button changes to red and moves 2px (as expected)
3. Now click on the "ABC":

   - _1  works as expected
   - The _2  Element doesn't do anything
   - The _3  remains in the :active state

The HTML should be valid. The code above is working on Chrome and Edge. I expcect that while clicking on the ::before content (ABC) the Links have to change to red and also adding the offset of 2px. The problem I'm facing is that its not possible in Firefox to use :active and ::before at the same link (`<a>`) Element.

Why I use the ::before content? Because in later situation I'm using FontAwesome which is adding the Icons to the ::before content:

Comment: Try adding `.test {position:relative;}`

Comment: Wow Thanks, such easy... I was always focused on that fact, that the other browsers weren't affected.

Comment: @Stickers Can you also explain why that works, and why Chrome doesn't need it?

Comment: @MrLister I don't know. I guess it is a bug.